# Does the 1 MB block size limit include the header?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, consensus, block-header, blocksize

I was able to follow the code to [validation.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/validation.cpp#L2681):

```
// Size limits
if (block.vtx.empty() || block.vtx.size() > MAX_BLOCK_BASE_SIZE || ::GetSerializeSize(block, SER_NETWORK, PROTOCOL_VERSION | SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION_NO_WITNESS) > MAX_BLOCK_BASE_SIZE)
    return state.DoS(100, false, REJECT_INVALID, "bad-blk-length", false, "size limits failed");
```

and [serialize.h](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/serialize.h#L954):

```
template <typename T>
size_t GetSerializeSize(const T& t, int nType, int nVersion = 0)
{
    return (CSizeComputer(nType, nVersion) << t).size();
}
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out what `CSizeComputer` is doing. Does `GetSerializeSize` include the block header in the value it returns?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41196/how-is-the-size-of-a-block-calculated

Comment: I'm not treating it as a duplicate as a question about Bitcoin Core's serialization code is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CSizeComputer` is a serialization stream that discards all data written, and just counts how many bytes were produced. It is inlined, and the compiler in most cases actually avoids computing the bytes.

So, `GetSerializeSize(block, SER_NETWORK, PROTOCOL_VERSION | SERIALIZE_TRANSACTION_NO_WITNESS)` just computes how many bytes would be produced when serializing a block for the network ignoring witnesses.

As blocks on the network indeed are prefixed by their header (and transaction count), those do contribute towards the maximum block size.